# NetworkX installed but can't import it into Python IDLE

Tags: python, networkx

Need help to confirm my NetworkX Installation and to import NetworkX into Python IDLE successfully.

I have Mac OS X 10.7.5 and I have Python 3.3 Application installed.  I have previously used Python 3.3 successfully.

I installed Network X by performing the following steps:

```
 1. downloaded networkx-1.8.1.tar.gz  into my Downloads folder
 2. double clicked on the the  tar.gz file, and the contents were extracted 
    in a subfolder called networkx-1.8.1
 3. went into Mac Terminal and changed my directory to the Downloads/networkx-1.8.1 folder
 4. I entered the following Terminal command to install Networkx:  
    sudo python ./setup.py install  
    This installation appears to be successful.
 5. I opened IDLE and typed:  import networkx as nx, and I received the following error
    message:

   ERROR MESSAGE:

   >>> import networkx as nx
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
       import networkx as nx
   ImportError: No module named 'networkx'
   >>>
```

My questions are:
     1.  Do you know if NetworkX compatible with Python 3.3 ? 
     2.  Do you know how I can import NetworkX into IDLE so that I can use it ?

Many many thanks for any assistance you can provide.  :-)

Comment: NetworkX does work with Python3.3: https://travis-ci.org/networkx/networkx

Comment: Did you use the same version of Python that IDLE uses to install NetworkX?

Comment: I am not sure how to check if my Python 3.3 version will work with NetworkX 1.8.1.   I thought NetworkX 1.8.1 installed successfully based on the steps I listed above as I did not receive any error message in Mac Terminal.  But, when I went into IDLE, Python does not seem to know here to find NetworkX when I try to import it. I am wondering if I need to tell Python IDLE which directory to find NetworkX in.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on a Fedora 20 system. The networkx module had been installed by the end user and it got very restrictive in permissions (700 for directories, 600 for files).

It would fail even for that user himself, but if the program loading the module was executed via sudo it would work.

Finally, changing the permissions to all the files under /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.9 to 755/644 made the module visible and the program worked.

(Your library location may be different of course). We run Python 2.7.5.

Comment: I have the same problem: My machine is Ubuntu 14.04, python version :2.7. I try to do "sudo chmod -R 777 ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx". But it still doesn't work. Can you post your code hwo to chomd the permission?